# How to get information about the fields where the term was found

Tags: c#, .net-core, lucene.net

I try to find a way to get information about the fields where the search term was found, to mention it in a search result list.

Like: "Found in 'Description'", "Found in 'Title'", etc.

I don't find any information about the matching field in the `TopDocs` (or `TopFieldDocs`) or in the `ScoreDocs`

(I'm currently using Lucene.Net 4.8.0-beta00005, which is compatible with .NET Core)

Any Ideas? Thanks in advance.